# How to add a Gift Card type product to the cart via graphql

Tags: magento2, graphql

I can't work out the syntax for adding a Gift Card product to the cart using Graphql. What product options need setting?

```php
mutation AddProductToCart($cartId: String!, $product: CartItemInput!) {
    addProductsToCart(cartId: $cartId, cartItems: [$product]) {
        cart {
            id
            ...CartTriggerFragment
            ...MiniCartFragment
            __typename
        }
        __typename
    }
}

fragment CartTriggerFragment on Cart {
    id
    total_quantity
    __typename
}

fragment MiniCartFragment on Cart {
    id
    total_quantity
    prices {
        subtotal_excluding_tax {
            currency
            value
            __typename
        }
        subtotal_including_tax {
            currency
            value
            __typename
        }
        __typename
    }
    ...ProductListFragment
    __typename
}

fragment ProductListFragment on Cart {
    id
    items {
        uid
        product {
            uid
            name
            sku
            url_key
            thumbnail {
                url
                __typename
            }
            stock_status
            ... on ConfigurableProduct {
                variants {
                    attributes {
                        uid
                        __typename
                    }
                    product {
                        uid
                        thumbnail {
                            url
                            __typename
                        }
                        __typename
                    }
                    __typename
                }
                __typename
            }
            __typename
        }
        prices {
            price {
                currency
                value
                __typename
            }
            total_item_discount {
                value
                __typename
            }
            __typename
        }
        quantity
        ... on ConfigurableCartItem {
            configurable_options {
                configurable_product_option_uid
                option_label
                configurable_product_option_value_uid
                value_label
                __typename
            }
            __typename
        }
        __typename
    }
    __typename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send following request

```
mutation ($cartId: String!, $cartItems: [CartItemInput!]!) {
  addProductsToCart(cartId: $cartId, cartItems: $cartItems) {
    cart {
      id
      items {
        uid
        quantity
        product {
          sku
          name
          thumbnail {
            url
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where the variables passed for gift card are

```
{
    "cartId": "{cart id token}",
    "cartItems": [
        {
            "sku": "{product sku}",
            "quantity": {qty},
            "entered_options": [
                {
                    "uid": "Z2lmdGNhcmQvZ2lmdGNhcmRfc2VuZGVyX25hbWU=",
                    "value": "{sender name}"
                },
                {
                    "uid": "Z2lmdGNhcmQvZ2lmdGNhcmRfc2VuZGVyX2VtYWls",
                    "value": "{sender email}"
                },
                {
                    "uid": "Z2lmdGNhcmQvZ2lmdGNhcmRfcmVjaXBpZW50X25hbWU=",
                    "value": "{Recipient name}"
                },
                {
                    "uid": "Z2lmdGNhcmQvZ2lmdGNhcmRfcmVjaXBpZW50X2VtYWls",
                    "value": "{Recipient email}"
                },
                {
                    "uid": "Z2lmdGNhcmQvZ2lmdGNhcmRfbWVzc2FnZQ==",
                    "value": "{message}"
                },
                {
                    "uid": "Z2lmdGNhcmQvY3VzdG9tX2dpZnRjYXJkX2Ftb3VudA==",
                    "value": "{amount}"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

the above `uids` are base64 encoded with following text prefixed with type `giftcard/`-

1. giftcard_sender_name
2. giftcard_sender_email
3. giftcard_recipient_name
4. giftcard_recipient_email
5. custom_giftcard_amount
6. giftcard_amount

example -

```
giftcard/giftcard_sender_name = Z2lmdGNhcmQvZ2lmdGNhcmRfc2VuZGVyX25hbWU=
```